# Changing the path in Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.mappath

I want to put in the string `name` into the code so i can create a folder named by the textbox input.  How can I modify this code to do that?

```
string name = txtUsername.Text;
string path = Server.MapPath("~/here the string name /");

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: string path = Server.MapPath("~/" + name + "/");

Comment: If i understood your question correctly you shoud do  `string path= Server.MapPath("~\"+name)`

Answer (score 2):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/" + name);
```